# Xpath: Select only non-nested pre tags

Tags: html, xpath, pre

Can anyone help me with a xpath selector to select all the `pre` tags within a page, but only if they are not within another `pre` tag? (even if multiple levels deep)

It would be awesome if this could all be done within one selector, rather than just selecting all `pre` tags and breaking if they have `pre` as a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? `//pre[not(ancestor::pre)]`

Answer (score 2):

Or for completeness, in XPath 2.0

```
//pre except //pre//pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//pre[not(ancestor::pre)]
```